# C# How to optimize this small piece of code correctly?

Tags: c#, mongodb, code-cleanup

I've written a small program where I need to insert some objects (employees in my case) in my MongoDB database. Each employee needs to get a random name from a predefined list with strings.

This is what I came up with and is working:

```
class Program
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("testdb");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Employee>("testcollection");

        Random random = new Random();
        List<string> names = new List<string>() {"John","Matthew","Chris"};
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int nameIndex      = random.Next(0, 3);  
            string nameValue   = names[nameIndex];  
            Employee employee = new Employee
            { 
                Name = nameValue
            };

           collection.Save(employee);
         }
     }

}
```

However, this code feels like a bit dirty and I am lookingfor a nice way to clean this up. Especially if I want to add more properties to my employee object.

**Edit:** @Eric Lippert
Of course! To start with, practically everything happens in the main method. With a single list it's fine, but I'd like to add more data to my employee object. It won't be tiny in the future.

So, if I want to add a few more List's, I have to duplicate my current code. For example, I'd like to iterate over another list with job types (10 items) and another one for locations (50 items). For each property I want to add to my Employee-object, I have to write a new line of the Next()-function from my Random object.

**Edit 3:**

```
public static IMongoDatabase Connect()
{
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    var db = client.GetDatabase("testdb");
    return db;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Connect();
    var collection = db.GetCollection<Employee>("testcollection");
}
```

Error: The name 'db' doesnt exist in the current context.

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to clean up this tiny program? Start by saying what feels "dirty" to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply more random values from other lists you can do the following, which basically comes down to removing the unnecessary nameIndex and nameValue variables:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee
    { 
        Name = names[random.Next(0, names.Count)]
    };

    collection.Save(employee);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brings me closer to an ideal piece of code. Is it useful to put the databaseconnection in a seperate function?

Comment: Separating database connection details from logic is recommendable, but I think you should apply other logic even more, like use "using" when you're using IDisposables.

Comment: I've edited my original post. I am not sure how I need to implement the "using" like in IDisposables, since I haven't used it before. However, I tried to separate the database connection from the rest of the logic, but it failed unfortunately.

Comment: Forget about the using. That will come when you have more logic and complexity. Your separation of the connection would be fine except for the last line, which is part of your current logic, not part of getting a database connection: remove var collection = db.GetCollection<Employee>("testcollection"); And also create a new class and put your logic there. Don't put it in Main, since that will result in the weird requirement of making all Methods and Properties static.

Comment: And I think you are struggling with the logic of returning the right object. Change the return type of Connect from void to IMongoDatabase and return db.

Comment: Edited my post (Edit 3). If I change my code, I'd get the error db doesnt exist in the current context.

Comment: Because you haven't declared and initiated db. You are just calling Connect() and not use it's returning value. Change it to var db = Connect(); And may I recommend you to look into a basic C# course, because calling methods, using it's results and declaring variables should be something you should be familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I agree with you and I'm actually busy with basic C# courses on Udemy, but it takes some time. Back to the post, the var db = Connect(); was something I tried earlier, but the result was that '   collection.Save(employee);' gives me an error; the one I mentioned before in Edit 3 'does not contain a defintion for Save'.

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract the separate parts in to new classes say a `DatabaseSeeder` and `Database`, this just cleans up the responsibilities instead of having it all in the `main` method

```
class Program
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Database
    {
        public ICollection<Employee> GetCollection()
        {
             MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var db = server.GetDatabase("testdb");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Employee>("testcollection");
        }
    }

    public class DatabaseSeeder
    {
        private ICollection<Employee> collection;

        public DatabaseSeeder(ICollection<Employee> collection)
        {
            this.collection = collection;
        }

        public void Seed()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            List<string> names = new List<string>() {"John","Matthew","Chris"};
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int nameIndex      = random.Next(0, 3);  
                string nameValue   = names[nameIndex];  
                Employee employee = new Employee
                { 
                    Name = nameValue
                };

               collection.Save(employee);
             }
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new Database().GetCollection();

        var databaseSeeder = new DatabaseSeeder(collection);

        databaseSeeder.Seed();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this code, but I get two errors. (1) 'ICollection<Employee> GetCollection' -> Not all code paths return a value and (2) 'ICollection<Employee>' does not contain a defintion for Save and 'Save' and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<Employee>'

Comment: Looks like you might be using an older version of the mongo driver

Comment: That's correct, I am using the 2.3.0 version, since I couldn't make the code work with the latest version 2.4.0.

Comment: I think if you remove the generic signature it'll be fine

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but remove the generic signature? If I remove the "<Employee>'s" , VS returns more errors